# How can I use a child of one element to toggle a class on another element with jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to edit a wordpress plugin using jQuery. I've added a button to one row of the layout (.first-row) and am trying use it to toggle a class on the row below (.second-row).

I'm not sure how to do this - I've tried using `.closest` to select the second row and toggle the class, but this doesn't seem to work. I've also tried using `.next` and `.find`, but haven't had any success.

I can't remember how I did it, but I managed to get close earlier - the problem was that if I clicked either of the buttons, it toggled the class on both of the divs with that class, and not the one below the specific button clicked. (This is why I included two of the same layout.)

Here's my JS Fiddle example.

https://jsfiddle.net/v71sytLf/5/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="upper-section"></div>
    <div class="lower-section">
        <div class="first-row"></div>
        <div class="second-row"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="upper-section"></div>
    <div class="lower-section">
        <div class="first-row"></div>
        <div class="second-row"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:275px;
  background:pink;
  margin-right:24px;
}

.upper-section {
  height:200px;
}

.first-row {
  height:55px;
  background:purple;
}

.second-row {
  height:55px;
  background:yellow;
}

.second-row.open {
  background:blue;
}

.button {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  right:0;
  background:orange;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

  $(".first-row").append("<span class='button'>Button</span>");

  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".second-row").toggleClass("open");
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to have the button DOM directly to make it easier to trigger actions. For accessibility reasons, prefer  element as button that does something and does not link to anything. Then, trigger relatively using jQuery's parent and next selectors.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="upper-section"></div>
  <div class="lower-section">
    <div class="first-row">
      <button class="button">Button</button>
    </div>      
    <div class="second-row"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="upper-section"></div>
  <div class="lower-section">
    <div class="first-row">
      <button class="button">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="second-row"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next(".second-row").toggleClass("open");
    });
  
});
```

Here's the updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0xq8w9sm/1/